Is this menu bar message supposed to be in Russian?
I recently got enough rep to access moderator tools.  The message notifying me of this in my "Achievements" menu was partially in Russian.  Is this due to a bug, some weird setting in my browser that I need to change, or an in-joke that I'm unaware of?


https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376522/wrong-language-in-recent-achievements old problem, go to meta and find the solution if any, add to the existing complaints if not, or accept that it's not going to be fixed.

This old bug is now fixed (or should be)
There is a staff answer on the "old problem" question that Nij linked:

Thanks for the report! Okay, I've fixed this to correctly provide per site translations for the privilege help text.
The explanation is basically the same as past incarnations of this issue where we've had a "first hit; first cached" issue. The simple version of the fix is to just do the localization each time and never store the result.

I will also echo KyleMit's last line: "Oh, and congrats on earning the vote up 'access moderator tools' privilege!"
